# How to stop one body when collide with another body [Box2d]

Tags: android, box2d, libgdx

I am developing a game using LibGDX platform and box2D in which I am moving one body(Dynamic) with the help of `tocuhPad` motion of LibGDX using

`testBody1.setTransform(new Vector2(x,y), 0);`

method and there are another bodies(Static) on the way with which the dynamic body collide.What I want is that when my dynamic body collide with the static one, none of them will overlap with each other that is not happening yet. Right now they are overlapping each other by applying force and moving static body.So, how can I prevent the collision of both bodies?

Answer (score 0):

```
testBody1->SetLinearVelocity(b2Vec2(0, 0));
```

Comment: Hi, I had already tried it, in this the dynamic body is not overlapping but it is putting force on static body that the static body start moving in another direction that I don't want.

Comment: static body can't move from impulse, because it's static !

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing that you check when your dynamic body collide with static body in BeginContact method. As they collide then you set dynamic body speed zero.